# Best practice for implementing frontend using laravel and vue

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2

I'm developing a large scale application base on Laravel 5.4. I'm wondering what is the best practice for implementing fronend for large scale application? Implementing on laravel blade for all styling and html rendering and using vue for interactivity or using blade to call vue components and implementing all stuff is vue? Let's see some examples:

**This is first approach:**

In laravel blade:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
  <customer-search></customer-search>
  <customer-table></customer-table>
@endsection
```

then customer-search component would be:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form action="/customer" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="name" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" :value="name" />
      <submit @click="search">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        name: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      search() {
        // Get data from server, update related data model for using in customer table, ...
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and customer-table component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Access</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="customer in customers">
          <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
          <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
```

**Second approach:**
blade:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
  <customer-index>
    <form action="/customer" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="name" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" :value="name" />
      <submit @click="search">Search</button>
    </form>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Access</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="customer in customers">
          <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
          <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </customer-index>
@endsection
```

and customer-index component:

```
<tempalte>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        name: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      search() {
        // Get data from server, update related data model for using in customer table, ...
      },
      // Other methods, ...
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Third possibility:**
Third possibility is try to using second approach and go more in depth on components. For example using a component for tables, a component for forms, a component for inputs, a component for buttons, ...
Which one should i use to avid spending much time in fronend and also have a integrated frontend?

Comment: These are series of laracast that may help https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/1

Comment: I watched all them 3 times. Not helping to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue components should always be loosely coupled so they can be reused in other places and even in other projects.

You should use the minimal amount of markup possible in your vue components, so that they are portable and can be reused without requiring you to edit them.

Obviously this is an opinion based question, but the above is, in my opinion at least, best practice.

Comment: Then why they call vue a 'frontend framework'? Let say you're going to use twitter bootstrap, where you include bootstrap styling chunks?

Comment: If you use semantic class names on your vue template elements you can then use whatever UI framework you want and just extend the existing classes in that framework.